# Load-Balanced Jenkins setup

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-efs

I have encountered an issue with my Jenkins instances. I have set up two instances that share a shared home directory using AWS EFS. However, I have noticed that when I build projects in Jenkins, the build numbers are not syncing properly between the instances. For example, if build number 32 is on instance 1, it will not show up on instance 2.

I believe this problem should not be occurring since the shared home directory ensures that all data about jobs, users, workspaces, etc. is shared across both instances. Currently, the build numbers only sync when I manually restart Jenkins on both servers. However, this is not the ideal approach.

My ultimate goal is to set up a load-balanced Jenkins environment with these two servers. I am using EC2 to run Jenkins and utilizing AWS ALB for load balancing. Can you please provide guidance on how I can fix this issue and ensure that the build numbers sync properly between the instances without the need for manual restarts?

I restarted the jenkins servers manually and it worked, but its not the ideal approach. I checked the efs directory of both instances,there all builds are there. Only issue is on the jenkins UI, those build numbers aren't syncing.